# How to Pass Array in Body of POST Request Using Volley In Android

Tags: android, android-volley

**Here The Code i am using for sending array in body of Volley Request. But its showing Unexpected response code 500.**

**Here is the Postman Post Request Image**

[image]

> here i am declaring variable of array

```
private ArrayList<Integer> medicine_id = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> code = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> expiry_date = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> batch_no = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> qty = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Double> cost = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Double> total = new ArrayList<>();
```

> here i am adding value in my declared variables

```
medicine_id.add(618);
code.add(202012011);
expiry_date.add("2021-01-09");
batch_no.add("1");
qty.add(1);
cost.add((double) 1234);
total.add((double) 2468);
```

> here is the code request i am using for Post Request method

```
try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SelectedPurchaseActivity.this);
        String URL = "http://khadizamedicinecorner.com/DokanPos/api/purchase/item-save";
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("purchase_no", "87676767");
        jsonBody.put("supplier", 7);
        jsonBody.put("date", "2020-12-02");
        jsonBody.put("p_type", "Cash");
        jsonBody.put("medicine_id",medicine_id);
        jsonBody.put("code", code);
        jsonBody.put("expiry_date", expiry_date);
        jsonBody.put("batch_no", batch_no);
        jsonBody.put("qty", qty);
        jsonBody.put("cost", cost);
        jsonBody.put("total", total);
        jsonBody.put("totalQty", 2);
        jsonBody.put("subTotal", 2468);
        jsonBody.put("discount", 3);
        jsonBody.put("d_type", "%");
        jsonBody.put("payable", 2394);
        jsonBody.put("paid", 3);
        jsonBody.put("due", 2391);
    
        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
```

> Here is the String Request to get the string response after posting
> data successfully

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new 
        Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY Response", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY Error", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }
    
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }
    
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Authorization", token);
                return params;
            }
    
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constant.SAVE_ITEM,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(SelectedPurchaseActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(SelectedPurchaseActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("purchase_no", "87676767");
                    params.put("supplier", "7");
                    params.put("date", "2020-12-02");
                    params.put("p_type", "Cash");
                    params.put("medicine_id[]","618");
                    params.put("code[]", "202012011");
                    params.put("expiry_date[]", "2021-01-09");
                    params.put("batch_no[]", "1");
                    params.put("qty[]", "1");
                    params.put("cost[]", "1234");
                    params.put("total[]", "2468");
                    params.put("totalQty", "2");
                    params.put("subTotal", "2468");
                    params.put("discount", "3");
                    params.put("d_type", "%");
                    params.put("payable", "2394");
                    params.put("paid", "3");
                    params.put("due", "2391");
                    return params;
                }
    
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Authorization", token);
                    return params;
                }
    
            };
    
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SelectedPurchaseActivity.this);
            queue.add(stringRequest);
```